# Is it possible to arrange the key values in preferred order without changing the keys in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to receive input as a dictionary, and rearrange the key values in ascending order without changing the keys.

Ex: Input:

```
{"Hi:5, "Hey":3, "Hello":10}
```

Output

```
{"Hi":3, "Hey":5, "Hello":10}
```

Comment: Dictionaries, particularly in python 2.7, are arbitrarily ordered. Use an `OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: You can also check this: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to change the order of the values of the keys here is some simple code

```
example = {"Hi":5, "Hey":3, "Hello":10} #Your dictionary
VALUES = [] #Here the values of the keys will be stored
#Get all the values of the dict keys
for item in example:
    value = example[item]
    VALUES.append(value)

VALUES.sort() #Sorts them from low number to high

i=0
for item in example:
    example[item] = VALUES[i]
    i +=1
```

This would ouput the following:

```
{'Hi': 3, 'Hey': 5, 'Hello': 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could unpack it into lists then sort the list with values and then repack like this:

```
stuff = {"Hi":5, "Hey":3, "Hello":10}
keys = []
values = []

for key in stuff.keys():
    keys.append(key)
    values.append(stuff[key])

values.sort()

i = 0
for key in stuff.keys():
    stuff[key] = values[i]
    i += 1

print stuff
```